# Changing directory on SFTP server with Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I have successfully run this script on development, but on production the file structure is slightly difference and I am getting the 'FileNotFoundError: Errno 2 error No such file' error code.

When I use the root login, I believe I land on this directory:

```
/root
```

The directory I need to work from is:

```
/BackupStorage/Test/Here
```

I believe I'm getting the error because my session is trying to run from the `/root` directory. How do I change directory to `/BackupStorage/Test/Here`? Or am I completely wrong?

```
local_path = r'C:\Data\Scripts\Trial\Test\Here'
remote_path = f'/BackupStorage/Test/Here'

hostname = 'hostname1'
password = 'password123'
username = 'root'
port = 22

print(f'Connecting to {hostname} ...')
session = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
session.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(session)
print(f'Connected to {hostname} - Remote Session Opened')

latest_time = -1
latest = None

# Below for loop finds latest sub-directory

for file_attr in sftp.listdir_attr(path=remote_path):
    if stat.S_ISDIR(file_attr.st_mode) and file_attr.st_mtime > latest_time:
        latest_time = file_attr.st_mtime
        latest = file_attr.filename

# Below for loop finds the .zip file within latest sub-directory
for file_attr in sftp.listdir_attr(path=f'{remote_path}/{latest}'):
    if file_attr.filename.endswith('.zip'):
        sftp.get(
            f'{remote_path}/{latest}/{file_attr.filename}',
            f'{local_path}\{file_attr.filename}'
        )
        print(f'Most recent {branch_name} file successfully retrieved.')

session.close
print('Remote Session Closed.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SFTPClient.chdir`:

```
sftp.chdir(path)
```

---

Or simply use absolute paths or correct relative paths to the home with other methods.